# How can I parse non-tagged data from beautiful soup output?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the following data extracted with beautiful soup.

```
{"currentLink":"/torrance-ca-90510/","regionId":96168,"displayRegionName":"90510"}],"universities":[]},"showAttributeLinks":null}},"mapState":{"customRegionPolygonWkt":null,"schoolPolygonWkt":null,"isCurrentLocationSearch":false,"userPosition":{"lat":null,"lon":null}},"regionState":{"regionInfo":[{"regionType":6,"regionId":54722,"regionName":"Torrance","displayName":"Torrance CA","isPointRegion":false}],"regionBounds":{"north":33.887061,"east":-118.308127,"south":33.780217,"west":-118.394107}},"searchPageSeoObject":{"baseUrl":"/torrance-ca/","windowTitle":"Torrance CA Real Estate - Torrance CA Homes For Sale | Zillow","metaDescription":"Zillow has 100 homes for sale in Torrance CA. View listing photos, review sales history, and use our detailed real estate filters to find the perfect place."},"abTrials":{"SXP_HDP_CONTINGENT_V2":"ON","SXP_REGION_AUTOCOMPLETE_SOURCE":"TRULIA","RE_Move_In_Date_Filter":"TEST","SXP_SENTRY":"ON","SEOTEST__SXP_LIST_ONLY_SRP":"CONTROL","SXP_SAVE_SEARCH_COLOR":"CONTROL","SXP_REACT_FOOTER_DESKTOP":"CONTROL","RE_Web_PersonalizedSort":"CONTROL","ACQ_Search_Filters_Upsell":"CONTROL","VARIANTS_BDP_768_PLUS":"CONTROL","SXP_FLOATING_ACTION_BAR":"ON","SET_CTA_COUNTLESS":"CONTROL","SXP_LISTING_SUBTYPE":"CONTROL","SXP_Search_Refinement_Filters":"CONTROL","RE_SearchByBuildingName":"TEST","SXP_PREXIT_CLAIMS_INFO":"ENABLED","SXP_NONMLS_OFF":"CONTROL","SXP_PARTIAL_PAGE_LOAD_REFACTOR":"CONTROL","SXP_NAV_AD_LOADING":"CONTROL","ACT_FILTER_ON_LAND":"CONTROL","SXP_PHOTO_CAROUSEL":"CONTROL","SEO__SXP_REMOVE_ANCHOR_TEXT":"CONTROL","DXP_NEW_MAP_DOTS_WEB":"CONTROL","SXP_ACT_REMOVE_SEARCHBOX_GLEAM":"NO_GLEAM","SXP_Exclude_Referer":"TEST","SXP_PAGE_LOAD":"FASTER","RE_Rentals_Badging_v1":"CONTROL","SXP_REACT_GPT":"REMOVED","SXP_QU_PHASE_2":"ON","RE_HDP_REDIRECT":"CONTROL","RE_Search_Refinement_Filters":"CONTROL","MIGHTY_MONTH_2022_HOLDOUT":"MIGHTY_MONTH_ON","SXP_NEW_LANE_CLICKSTREAM":"ON","SXP_REDUCED_SERVER_SIDE_RENDER":"CONTROL","SXP_DelayJS":"AFTER_LOAD","ACQ_Banner_Suppression":"CONTROL","GS_RATING_CLEANUP":"CONTROL","SXP_DEFERRED_RENDERER":"ASYNC_INITIAL_HYDRATE","SXP_STREETVIEW_REQUEST_TYPE":"CONTROL","RE_RentalsHomesForYouSort":"CONTROL","SP_FOR_RENT_PAGE":"CONTROL","Activation_NewLane_Metrics_Enabled":"DISABLED","SEOTEST__SXP_REMOVE_WHY_ZILLOW":"REMOVE_WHY_ZILLOW","Activation_Enabled":"ENABLED","DXP_RTB_LINKING":"ON","DXP_PHOTO_CAROUSEL":"CONTROL","DXP_MAP_ICONS":"CONTROL","WEB_HIDDEN_HOMES_2022":"ON","SXP_Rentals_Apartment_Community_Filter":"TEST","DXP_HOMEPAGE_OMP_CLIENT_REFACTOR":"ON","SXP_WOW_LIST_CARD":"CONTROL","SXP_KF_FILTERS_AC":"ON","SXP_SDS_INTEGRATION":"USE_FOR_ALL","SXP_MOBILE_MAP_PRIORITY":"CONTROL","SXP_MAP_DOT_STYLE":"CONTROL","Activation_GA_Metrics_Enabled":"ENABLED","SXP_Pers_SimilarResults":"CONTROL","RE_RentalHomeDetailsService":"CONTROL","ACQ_SigninSRP_Module":"Variant_Module_A","DXP_CONST_PROPCARD_MAPVIEW":"CONTROL","SXP_FLYBAR_PSL_ZGSEARCH":"ON","ADS_Tagless":"Casale_On","SEOTEST__NC_H1":"ALTERNATE","SXP_FLYBAR_REGION_API":"CONTROL","RMX_3RD_PARTY_P1":"ON","RUM_VIA_PRE_ENDPOINT":"TREATMENT_OFF","DXP_CONST_PROPCARD_LISTVIEW":"ON","SXP_EVENT_MARKUP":"CONTROL","SXP_SEARCH_DISPATCHER_SERVICE":"CONTROL","SXP_DISPLAY_AD_LOADING":"CONTROL","SP_ZO_HDP_PAGE":"CONTROL","DXP_DYNAMIC_ADS":"CONTROL","DXP_MAP_DOT_COLORS":"CONTROL","DESKTOP_COMMUTE_FILTER_MVP":"CONTROL","DXP_AUTH_GATED_COLLECTIONS":"ON","RE_FR_Photo_Carousel":"CONTROL","ADT_TOP_SLOT_SRP":"ONSITE_MESSAGING","DXP_HIDE_HOME":"CONTROL","VL_BDP_SSR_QUERY":"CONTROL_CACHED","VL_BDP_NEW_TAB":"CONTROL","SXP_PREXIT_CLAIMS_CHECK":"ENABLED","SEOTEST__SXP_SEO_TEST":"CONTROL","SXP_OPEN_HOUSE_FLEX":"OPEN_HOUSE_BOOSTED","SP_FOR_SALE_PAGE":"CONTROL","SXP_NO_SRPTOGGLE":"CONTROL","SXP_PAGINATION":"LEGACY_PAGINATION","SXP_KF_FILTERS_V2":"ON","SXP_MLS_NONMLS_FILTER":"CONTROL","DXP_MULTIPLE_COLLECTIONS":"ON","RE_GuidedSearchFiltersPOC":"CONTROL","SXP_3DHOME_FILTER":"ON","SP_BUILDING_PAGE":"CONTROL","SXP_QU_MIGRATION":"ON","ACQ_MOBILE_UPSELL_SXP":"CONTROL","SXP_LIST_ONLY_SRP":"CONTROL","RE_JanusBrainSort":"TEST_ALL_STATES","SEOTEST__RE_ForRentForSaleSRPBreadcrumbs":"CONTROL","SXP_MAKE_ME_MOVE":"REMOVED","SHO_GA_ResultsTotalEvent":"ON","DXP_MAP_DOTS_WEB":"ON","SXP_MULTIREGION_SEARCH":"CONTROL","DXP_HERO_SHORTENING":"ON","SXP_VISUAL_AUDIT_2021":"ON","SXP_HDP_BLUE_TO_RED":"ON","HDP_DESKTOP_LAYOUT_TOPNAV":"CONTROL","SXP_HEADER_TAG_WRAPPER":"ON","DXP_HOMEPAGE_OMP":"ON","SXP_Multifamily_Filter":"MULTIFAMILY_SEPARATE","SXP_FOOTER":"RESPONSIVE_REACT","SP_PAID_BUILDER_PAGE":"VIA_SHOPPER_PLATFORM","SP_OFF_MARKET_PAGE":"VIA_SHOPPER_PLATFORM","SXP_KINGFISHER_FILTERS":"P1_PHASE_1","RE_SECOND_BOOST":"SLOT_4","DXP_TG_SCHOOLS_DISABLED":"CONTROL","ADT_PROGRESSIVE_MESSAGE":"CONTROL","SXP_Combined_Filter_Apartments_Condos":"TEST","DXP_HOME_RECS":"ON","SEOTEST__SXP_REACT_FOOTER_DESKTOP":"CONTROL","SXP_3DTOUR_MAP_DOT":"ON","DXP_SEE_MORE_RECS":"SCROLL_ON"},"cat1":{"searchResults":{"listResults":[{"zpid":"21328879","id":"21328879","providerListingId":null,"imgSrc":"https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/3e81a218088316bafa7b199e8dc4923f-p_e.jpg","hasImage":true,"detailUrl":"https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/20412-Wayne-Ave-Torrance-CA-90503/21328879_zpid/","statusType":"FOR_SALE","statusText":"House for sale","countryCurrency":"$","price":"$1,275,000","unformattedPrice":1275000,"address":"20412 Wayne Ave, Torrance, CA 90503","addressStreet":"20412 Wayne Ave","addressCity":"Torrance","addressState":"CA","addressZipcode":"90503","isUndisclosedAddress":false,"beds":4,"baths":2.0,"area":1890,"latLong":{"latitude":33.845936,"longitude":-118.37223},"isZillowOwned":false,"variableData":{"type":"OPEN_HOUSE","text":"Open: Sat. 12-3pm"},"badgeInfo":null,"hdpData":{"homeInfo":{"zpid":21328879,"streetAddress":"20412 Wayne Ave","zipcode":"90503","city":"Torrance","state":"CA","latitude":33.845936,"longitude":-118.37223,"price":1275000.0,"bathrooms":2.0,"bedrooms":4.0,"livingArea":1890.0,"homeType":"SINGLE_FAMILY","homeStatus":"FOR_SALE","daysOnZillow":-1,"isFeatured":false,"shouldHighlight":false,"zestimate":1264181,"rentZestimate":4699,"listing_sub_type":{"is_openHouse":true,"is_FSBA":true},"openHouse":"Sat. 12-3pm","isUnmappable":false,"isPreforeclosureAuction":false,"homeStatusForHDP":"FOR_SALE","priceForHDP":1275000.0,"open_house_info":{"open_house_showing":[{"open_house_start":1673726400000,"open_house_end":1673737200000},{"open_house_start":1673816400000,"open_house_end":1673827200000},{"open_house_start":1673902800000,"open_house_end":1673913600000}]},"isNonOwnerOccupied":true,"isPremierBuilder":false,"isZillowOwned":false,"currency":"USD","country":"USA","taxAssessedValue":171633.0,"lotAreaValue":7172.0,"lotAreaUnit":"sqft"}},"isSaved":false,"hasOpenHouse":true,"openHouseStartDate":"2023-01-14T12:00:00","openHouseEndDate":"2023-01-14T15:00:00","openHouseDescription":"Open House - 0:00 - 3:00 PM","isUserClaimingOwner":false,"isUserConfirmedClaim":false,"pgapt":"ForSale","sgapt":"For Sale (Broker)","zestimate":1264181,"shouldShowZestimateAsPrice":false,"has3DModel":true,"hasVideo":false,"isHomeRec":false,"brokerName":"Re/Max Estate Properties","hasAdditionalAttributions":true,"isFeaturedListing":false,"availabilityDate":null,"list":true,"relaxed":false},{"zpid":"2060330967","id":"2060330967","providerListingId":null,"imgSrc":"https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/f65a190c100bab31301becdba3cdf7cc-p_e.jpg","hasImage":true,"detailUrl":"https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/23701-S-Western-Ave-SPACE-244-Torrance-CA-90501/2060330967_zpid/","statusType":"FOR_SALE","statusText":"Home for sale","countryCurrency":"$","price":"$88,000","unformattedPrice":88000,"address":"23701 S Western Ave SPACE 244, Torrance, CA 90501","addressStreet":"23701 S Western Ave SPACE 244","addressCity":"Torrance","addressState":"CA","addressZipcode":"90501","isUndisclosedAddress":false,"beds":3,"baths":2.0,"area":1000,"latLong":{"latitude":33.809013,"longitude":-118.311035},"isZillowOwned":false,"variableData":{"type":"OPEN_HOUSE","text":"Open: Sat. 2-4pm"},"badgeInfo":null,"hdpData":{"homeInfo":{"zpid":2060330967,"streetAddress":"23701 S Western Ave SPACE 244","zipcode":"90501","city":"Torrance","state":"CA","latitude":33.809013,"longitude":-118.311035,"price":88000.0,"datePriceChanged":1673078400000,"bathrooms":2.0,"bedrooms":3.0,"livingArea":1000.0,"homeType":"MANUFACTURED","homeStatus":"FOR_SALE","daysOnZillow":-1,"isFeatured":false,"shouldHighlight":false,"listing_sub_type":{"is_openHouse":true,"is_FSBA":true},"openHouse":"Sat. 2-4pm","priceReduction":"$2,000 (Jan 7)","isUnmappable":false,"isPreforeclosureAuction":false,"homeStatusForHDP":"FOR_SALE","priceForHDP":88000.0,"open_house_info":{"open_house_showing":[{"open_house_start":1673733600000,"open_house_end":1673740800000},{"open_house_start":1673820000000,"open_house_end":1673827200000}]},"priceChange":-2000,"isNonOwnerOccupied":true,"isPremierBuilder":false,"isZillowOwned":false,"currency":"USD","country":"USA","unit":"Space 244","lotAreaValue":16.3319,"lotAreaUnit":"acres"}},"isSaved":false,"hasOpenHouse":true,"openHouseStartDate":"2023-01-14T14:00:00","openHouseEndDate":"2023-01-14T16:00:00","openHouseDescription":"Open House - 2:00 - 4:00 PM","isUserClaimingOwner":false,"isUserConfirmedClaim":false,"pgapt":"ForSale","sgapt":"For Sale (Broker)","zestimate":null,"shouldShowZestimateAsPrice":false,"has3DModel":false,"hasVideo":false,"isHomeRec":false,"brokerName":"eXp Realty of California, Inc.","hasAdditionalAttributions":true,"isFeaturedListing":false,"availabilityDate":null,"list":true,"relaxed":false},{"zpid":"21338409","id":"21338409","providerListingId":null,"imgSrc":"https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/1f90c7be6ceca4a76d64d904010f0cb7-p_e.jpg","hasImage":true,"detailUrl":"https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/25924-Matfield-Dr-Torrance-CA-90505/21338409_zpid/","statusType":"FOR_SALE","statusText":"House for sale","countryCurrency":"$","price":"$1,100,000","unformattedPrice":1100000,"address":"25924 Matfield Dr, Torrance, CA 90505","addressStreet":"25924 Matfield Dr","addressCity":"Torrance","addressState":"CA","addressZipcode":"90505","isUndisclosedAddress":false,"beds":4,"baths":3.0,"area":1531,"latLong":{"latitude":33.78651,"longitude":-118.334206},"isZillowOwned":false,"variableData":{"type":"OPEN_HOUSE","text":"Open: Sat. 1-4pm"},"badgeInfo":null,"hdpData":{"homeInfo":{"zpid":21338409,"streetAddress":"25924 Matfield Dr","zipcode":"90505","city":"Torrance","state":"CA","latitude":33.78651,"longitude":-118.334206,"price":1100000.0,"bathrooms":3.0,"bedrooms":4.0,"livingArea":1531.0,"homeType":"SINGLE_FAMILY","homeStatus":"FOR_SALE","daysOnZillow":-1,"isFeatured":false,"shouldHighlight":false,"zestimate":1100006,"rentZestimate":3800,"listing_sub_type":{"is_openHouse":true,"is_FSBA":true},"openHouse":"Sat. 1-4pm","isUnmappable":false,"isPreforeclosureAuction":false,"homeStatusForHDP":"FOR_SALE","priceForHDP":1100000.0,"open_house_info":{"open_house_showing":[{"open_house_start":1673730000000,"open_house_end":1673740800000},{"open_house_start":1673816400000,"open_house_end":1673827200000}]},"isNonOwnerOccupied":true,"isPremierBuilder":false,"isZillowOwned":false,"currency":"USD","country":"USA","taxAssessedValue":436335.0,"lotAreaValue":7987.0,"lotAreaUnit":"sqft"}},"isSaved":false,"hasOpenHouse":true,"openHouseStartDate":"2023-01-14T13:00:00","openHouseEndDate":"2023-01-14T16:00:00","openHouseDescription":"Open House - 1:00 - 4:00 PM","isUserClaimingOwner":false,"isUserConfirmedClaim":false,"pgapt":"ForSale","sgapt":"For Sale (Broker)","zestimate":1100006,"shouldShowZestimateAsPrice":false,"has3DModel":true,"hasVideo":false,"isHomeRec":false,"brokerName":"Equity Union","hasAdditionalAttributions":true,"isFeaturedListing":false,"availabilityDate":null,"list":true,"relaxed":false},{"zpid":"21337140","id":"21337140","providerListingId":null,"imgSrc":"https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/cb80b5736be022cbeeafb3bb77ec0e83-p_e.jpg","hasImage":true,"detailUrl":"https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/4068-Newton-St-Torrance-CA-90505/21337140_zpid/","statusType":"FOR_SALE","statusText":"House for sale","countryCurrency":"$","price":"$999,900","unformattedPrice":999900,"address":"4068 Newton St, Torrance, CA 90505","addressStreet":"4068 Newton St","addressCity":"Torrance","addressState":"CA","addressZipcode":"90505","isUndisclosedAddress":false,"beds":2,"baths":2.0,"area":1268,"latLong":{"latitude":33.803745,"longitude":-118.35658},"isZillowOwned":false,"variableData":{"type":"OPEN_HOUSE","text":"Open: Sat. 1-4pm"},"badgeInfo":null,"hdpData":{"homeInfo":{"zpid":21337140,"streetAddress":"4068 Newton St","zipcode":"90505","city":"Torrance","state":"CA","latitude":33.803745,"longitude":-118.35658,"price":999900.0,"bathrooms":2.0,"bedrooms":2.0,"livingArea":1268.0,"homeType":"SINGLE_FAMILY","homeStatus":"FOR_SALE","daysOnZillow":-1,"isFeatured":false,"shouldHighlight":false,"zestimate":999907,"rentZestimate":3999,"listing_sub_type":{"is_openHouse":true,"is_FSBA":true},"openHouse":"Sat. 1-4pm","isUnmappable":false,"isPreforeclosureAuction":false,"homeStatusForHDP":"FOR_SALE","priceForHDP":999900.0,"open_house_info":{"open_house_showing":[{"open_house_start":1673730000000,"open_house_end":1673740800000},{"open_house_start":1673816400000,"open_house_end":1673827200000}]},"isNonOwnerOccupied":true,"isPremierBuilder":false,"isZillowOwned":false,"currency":"USD","country":"USA","taxAssessedValue":521866.0,"lotAreaValue":5050.0,"lotAreaUnit":"sqft"}},"isSaved":false,"hasOpenHouse":true,"openHouseStartDate":"2023-01-14T13:00:00","openHouseEndDate":"2023-01-14T16:00:00","openHouseDescription":"Open House - 1:00 - 4:00 PM","isUserClaimingOwner":false,"isUserConfirmedClaim":false,"pgapt":"ForSale","sgapt":"For Sale (Broker)","zestimate":999907,"shouldShowZestimateAsPrice":false,"has3DModel":false,"hasVideo":false,"isHomeRec":false,"brokerName":"Compass","hasAdditionalAttributions":true,"isFeaturedListing":false,"availabilityDate":null,"list":true,"relaxed":false},{"zpid":"63093583","id":"63093583","providerListingId":null,"imgSrc":"https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/8eec0c61013d143353c8893258ad1770-p_e.jpg","hasImage":true,"detailUrl":"https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/3120-Sepulveda-Blvd-UNIT-414-Torrance-CA-90505/63093583_zpid/","statusType":"FOR_SALE","statusText":"Condo for sale","countryCurrency":"$","price":"$389,000","unformattedPrice":389000,"address":"3120 Sepulveda Blvd UNIT 414, Torrance, CA 90505","addressStreet":"3120 Sepulveda Blvd UNIT 414","addressCity":"Torrance","addressState":"CA","addressZipcode":"90505","isUndisclosedAddress":false,"beds":1,"baths":1.0,"area":526,"latLong":{"latitude":33.823784,"longitude":-118.34189},"isZillowOwned":false,"variableData":{"type":"OPEN_HOUSE","text":"Open: Sat. 1-4pm"},"badgeInfo":null,"hdpData":{"homeInfo":{"zpid":63093583,"streetAddress":"3120 Sepulveda Blvd UNIT 414","zipcode":"90505","city":"Torrance","state":"CA","latitude":33.823784,"longitude":-118.34189,"price":389000.0,"bathrooms":1.0,"bedrooms":1.0,"livingArea":526.0,"homeType":"CONDO","homeStatus":"FOR_SALE","daysOnZillow":-1,"isFeatured":false,"shouldHighlight":false,"zestimate":389001,"rentZestimate":2084,"listing_sub_type":{"is_openHouse":true,"is_FSBA":true},"openHouse":"Sat. 1-4pm","isUnmappable":false,"isPreforeclosureAuction":false,"homeStatusForHDP":"FOR_SALE","priceForHDP":389000.0,"open_house_info":{"open_house_showing":[{"open_house_start":1673730000000,"open_house_end":1673740800000}]},"isNonOwnerOccupied":true,"isPremierBuilder":false,"isZillowOwned":false,"currency":"USD","country":"USA","taxAssessedValue":360000.0,"unit":"Unit 414","lotAreaValue":1.0985,"lotAreaUnit":"acres"}},"isSaved":false,"hasOpenHouse":true,"openHouseStartDate":"2023-01-14T13:00:00","openHouseEndDate":"2023-01-14T16:00:00","openHouseDescription":"Open House - 1:00 - 4:00 PM","isUserClaimingOwner":false,"isUserConfirmedClaim":false,"pgapt":"ForSale","sgapt":"For Sale (Broker)","zestimate":389001,"shouldShowZestimateAsPrice":false,"has3DModel":false,"hasVideo":false,"isHomeRec":false,"brokerName":"Re/Max Estate Properties","hasAdditionalAttributions":true,"isFeaturedListing":false,"availabilityDate":null,"list":true,"relaxed":false},{"zpid":"21324245","id":"21324245","providerListingId":null,"imgSrc":"https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/4c47d6593842fdf0036f1805838c1673-p_e.jpg","hasImage":true,"detailUrl":"https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/417-Paseo-De-La-Playa-Redondo-Beach-CA-90277/21324245_zpid/","statusType":"FOR_SALE","statusText":"House for sale","countryCurrency":"$","price":"$19,995,000","unformattedPrice":19995000,"address":"417 Paseo De La Playa, Redondo Beach, CA 90277","addressStreet":"417 Paseo De La Playa","addressCity":"Redondo Beach","addressState":"CA","addressZipcode":"90277","isUndisclosedAddress":false,"beds":10,"baths":15.0,"area":15728,"latLong":{"latitude":33.810413,"longitude":-118.39131},"isZillowOwned":false,"variableData":{"type":"PRICE_REDUCTION","text":"$3,000,000 (Nov 10)"},"badgeInfo":null,"hdpData":{"homeInfo":{"zpid":21324245,"streetAddress":"417 Paseo De La Playa","zipcode":"90277","city":"Redondo Beach","state":"CA","latitude":33.810413,"longitude":-118.39131,"price":1.9995E7,"datePriceChanged":1668067200000,"bathrooms":15.0,"bedrooms":10.0,"livingArea":15728.0,"homeType":"SINGLE_FAMILY","homeStatus":"FOR_SALE","daysOnZillow":-1,"isFeatured":false,"shouldHighlight":false,"zestimate":17760922,"rentZestimate":83834,"listing_sub_type":{"is_FSBA":true},"priceReduction":"$3,000,000 (Nov 10)","isUnmappable":false,"isPreforeclosureAuction":false,"homeStatusForHDP":"FOR_SALE","priceForHDP":1.9995E7,"priceChange":-3000000,"isNonOwnerOccupied":true,"isPremierBuilder":false,"isZillowOwned":false,"currency":"USD","country":"USA","taxAssessedValue":1.2904489E7,"lotAreaValue":1.4407,"lotAreaUnit":"acres"}},"isSaved":false,"isUserClaimingOwner":false,"isUserConfirmedClaim":false,"pgapt":"ForSale","sgapt":"For Sale (Broker)","zestimate":17760922,"shouldShowZestimateAsPrice":false,"has3DModel":false,"hasVideo":false,"isHomeRec":false,"brokerName":"Douglas Elliman of California, Inc.","info6String":"Joshua Altman DRE # 01764587","hasAdditionalAttributions":true,"isFeaturedListing":false,"availabilityDate":null,"list":true,"relaxed":false},{"zpid":"21272955","id":"21272955","providerListingId":null,"imgSrc":"https://photos.zillowstatic.com/fp/0d9ac33c6a2d1c8683ec45e7aef895a5-p_e.jpg","hasImage":true,"detailUrl":"https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/3101-Plaza-Del-Amo-UNIT-5-Torrance-CA-90503/21272955_zpid/","statusType":"FOR_SALE","statusText":"Townhouse for sale","countryCurrency":"$","price":"$835,000","unformattedPrice":835000,"address":"3101 Plaza Del Amo UNIT 5, Torrance, CA 90503","addressStreet":"3101 Plaza Del Amo UNIT 5","addressCity":"Torrance","addressState":"CA","addressZipcode":"90503","isUndisclosedAddress":false,"beds":3,"baths":3.0,"area":1446,"latLong":{"latitude":33.828743,"longitude":-118.34023},"isZillowOwned":false,"variableData":{"type":"DAYS_ON","text":"3 days on Zillow"},"badgeInfo":null,"hdpData":{"homeInfo":{"zpid":21272955,"streetAddress":"3101 Plaza Del Amo UNIT 5","zipcode":"90503","city":"Torrance","state":"CA","latitude":33.828743,"longitude":-118.34023,"price":835000.0,"bathrooms":3.0,"bedrooms":3.0,"livingArea":1446.0,"homeType":"TOWNHOUSE","homeStatus":"FOR_SALE","daysOnZillow":-1,"isFeatured":false,"shouldHighlight":false,"zestimate":852600,"rentZestimate":3499,"listing_sub_type":{"is_FSBA":true},"isUnmappable":false,"isPreforeclosureAuction":false,"homeStatusForHDP":"FOR_SALE","priceForHDP":835000.0,"isNonOwnerOccupied":true,"isPremierBuilder":false,"isZillowOwned":false,"currency":"USD","country":"USA","taxAssessedValue":788066.0,"unit":"Unit 5","lotAreaValue":5.4866,"lotAreaUnit":"acres"}},"isSaved":false,"isUserClaimingOwner":false,"isUserConfirmedClaim":false,"pgapt":"ForSale","sgapt":"For Sale (Broker)","zestimate":852600,"shouldShowZestimateAsPrice":false,"has3DModel":false,"hasVideo":false,"isHomeRec":false,"brokerName":"RELO REDAC, Inc.","hasAdditionalAttributions":true,"isFeaturedListing":false,"availabilityDate":null,"list":true,"relaxed":false},
```

From what I can tell, this data exists in a section of the beautiful soup object within a < script > tag. I didn't include all data (there's a lot), but here's an excerpt of the last tag I can find before the region I'd like to extract.

```
<script data-zrr-shared-data-key="mobileSearchPageStore" type="application/json"><!--{"queryState":{"mapBounds":{"north":33.887061,"south":33.780217,"east":-118.308127,"west":-118.394107},"regionSelection":[{"regionId":54722,"regionType":6}],"isMapVisible":true,"filterState":{"sortSelection":{"value":"globalrelevanceex"},"isAllHomes":{"value":true}}},"filterDefinitions":{"keywords":{"id":"keywords","shortId":"att","labels":{"default":"Keywords","tracking":"Keyword"},"sortOrder":2,"type":"String","defaultValue":{"value":""},"exposedPillEnabled":true},"isPublicSchool":{"id":"isPublicSchool","shortId":"schp","labels":{"default":"Public"},"type":"Boolean","defaultValue":{"value":true}},"isCityView":{"id":"isCityView","shortId":"cityv","labels":
```

Is this json data? Is there a way to extract just this part of the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to parse the data with `json` module:

```py
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''\
<script data-zrr-shared-data-key="mobileSearchPageStore" type="application/json"><!--{"currentLink":"/torrance-ca-90510/","regionId":96168}--></script>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')


# get the right tag
data = soup.select_one('script[data-zrr-shared-data-key="mobileSearchPageStore"]')
# get the contents of this tag, strip the html comments
data = data.contents[0].strip('><!-')
# parse the data
data = json.loads(data)

# print the data
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{'currentLink': '/torrance-ca-90510/', 'regionId': 96168}
```